# Creating a lift system that will lift a pop up camper roof that has been changed from the original design

Tags: mechanisms

I have taken a pop up camper that was rotten and rebuilt it to serve as a portable blacksmith shop. I have built the new frame from wood, making it as light as I could but lets face it, the wood frame, T 1-11 siding and galvalume gable roof is heavier than the original pop up camper.
I fear using the lift system designed for the original light weight aluminum roof system to lift this heavier frame construction.
I have decided to build square tubular telescoping legs at each corner that will provide stable support and guidance as the roof lifts upward. The question I have is how or where can I get a center lift mechanism that I can position in the center of the floor and roof system, like a rack and pinion that is either hand cranked or motorized but the simpler the better. I am envisioning a heavy gauge square tube approx. 4 ft. high with a telescoping tube inside or alongside that lifts the center ridge beam approx. 4 ft. and once the roof rests at its maximum height, I would lock the 4 corner legs with pins to keep the roof in position. Then I can lower and remove the center lift system to get it out of the way while working inside. When lowering the roof, I just re-position the center rack and pinion lift system, lift the weight slightly off the 4 corner legs, release the pins and let the roof system down so it can travel down the road.

Comment: shopping questions are not allowed here

Comment: There exist a variety of screw, hydraulic jack, scissor lift, etc systems that might suffice.